# Cleaner code: Re-factor multiple nested if statements

Tags: c#, if-statement, refactoring

I have code that looks something like this:

```
if(condition1)
{
  //do some stuff
  if(condition2)
  {
   //do some other stuff
   if(condition3)
   {
       //do some more stuff
       if(condition4)
       { 
       //you probably got the point by now...
       }
   }
}
```

And I would like to re-factor it to code that looks better and is easier to follow.
So far the best I got Is:

```
do{    
    if(!condition1){break;}
    //do some stuff
    if(!condition2){break;}
    //do some other stuff
    if(!condition3){break;}
    //do some more stuff
    if(!condition4){break;}
    //you probably got the point by now...

}while(false);
```

My question is:
Is there another better way I am missing?

I don't think it is relevant, but I am using C#...

Comment: your refactoring suggestion is terrible.  there is no need to refactor the nested if statements.

Comment: @DwB Why do you think it is terrible? I find it easier to read, and easier to follow the idea behind the code.

Comment: your suggested change makes the code harder to read and makes it less ovbious.  the do - while construct is a looping mechanism that you are using as a goto mechanism.  If you feel the need to use a goto, the use a label and goto it.  If you must use some silly obfuscation, use a switch statement and fall through each case.

Comment: The switch would work if there was 1 item to switch on, which is not the case...

Comment: The starting code looks like the anti-pattern 'arrow code' - I need to find a link to it that.

Comment: I was curious about the anti-pattern 'arrow code'. I found this http://wiki.c2.com/?ArrowAntiPattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using C#, the idea of @dseibert could be extended a little bit more and made flexible using delegates, in this case [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549151.aspx). 
You could create a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6sh2ey19.aspx) that holds [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549151.aspx)'s and add as many functions with the signature **bool function(void)** as you want and then evaluate the result of all of them using [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx).

Three example functions to play with:

```
private bool isRed()
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("red");
    return true;
}

private bool isBlue()
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("blue");
    return false;
}

private bool isGreen()
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("green");
    return true;
}
```

List holding Funcs, that is filled with the test functions and initialized result:

```
var actions = new List<Func<bool>>();
actions.Add(() => isRed());
actions.Add(() => isGreen());
actions.Add(() => isBlue());
var result = true; // initial value
```

Evaluate all functions at once:

```
actions.ForEach(a => result &= a());
System.Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Now the only thing that you need to do is create a new method and add it to the list.

The downside of this solutions is that every method is always called even if the result is already false, but the code within the ForEach extension method could be optimized.

Comment: I love this way. I used to apply it everytime I can but with an Aggregate :)

Comment: Thanks @JeancarloFontalvo. Yes - Aggregate is a good solution. Another alternative would be to use List.Any or List.All :-)

Answer (score 3):

Possibly encapsulate the functionality you need for each boolean condition into a method and use the method instead of specifying condition1, condition2, condition3 etc.

```
private boolean isRed() {
//do some stuff
}

private boolean isBlue() {
//do some other stuff
}

private boolean isGreen() {
//do some more stuff
}

...

if(isRed() && isBlue() && isGreen()) {
//do some more stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but a switch won't be good here. There are multiple conditions here. A switch will be good for checking a value of 1 specific item.

Comment: I have another idea.  encapsulate conditions into methods.  I'll explain by changing my answer.

Comment: Still this will not solve the issue of getting deeper and deeper into the nested ifs